# How to add pop up window

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone application.
I would like to ask when I click on image popup vindow like username and password should come.
how to do this? which assembly and namespace I have to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokia has made a nice [example](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone) on how to use Popups. If you are starting out with Windows Phone programming I recommend you check out [this training series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) for free on channel 9 which will give you a tour around developing for Windows Phone 8.